# Flex:- how to make linkButton visible false in dataGrid based on some condition

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

i am using flex, and in my application i am using datGrid, inside that there are 6 to 7 columns
In the last column, there are 5 link buttons.
Now in dataGris i also have one status column. on tha basis of status, i want to hide some of these link buttons.
for example, if status is 'a' then button 2 and 3 should disaapear
and when status becomes 'b' some other buttons will be disaapear.
and it is also possible that diffrent rows can have diffrent status, and according to that linkButtons should disaapear.

how can i do this???
Please....
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the LinkButton's visible property to your DataGrid's status column or a custom function thereof.